# Intersection of (Toric varieties) and (Flag varieties)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, projective-varieties, toric-varieties

For me, a *variety* $X$ is assumed to be irreducible and normal over some algebraically closed field $k$ of characteristic zero.

I call $X$ a *toric variety* if it has an algebraic torus $T$ which embeds $T\hookrightarrow X$ as an open subset such that the action of $T$ on itself (multiplication) extends to an algebraic action on all of $X$.

I call $X$ a *flag variety* if $X\cong G/P$ for some connected reductive linear algebraic group $G$ and some parabolic subgroup $P\subseteq G$. Note that flag varieties are smooth and projective.

My question is this:

> Which varieties $X$ are simultaneously a toric variety and a flag variety?

Certainly such varieties $X$ need to be smooth and projective. Some examples:

(1) If $X=\mathbb{P}^n$, then this is certainly a toric variety, and it is a flag variety via $SL_n/P_n$ where $P_n$ is a maximal parabolic subgroup (not equal to all of $SL_n$).

(2) Products of the above example, e.g. $\mathbb{P}^1\times\mathbb{P}^1$, since toric and flag varieties are closed under taking products.

(3) Points since a point is clearly toric (the trivial torus action) and is of the form $G/G$.

(4) As a **non**-example, the homogeneous space $SL_3/B$ is a flag variety but not a toric variety ($B$ is the Borel subgroup). Indeed, it is clearly a flag variety, but its Cox ring is not a polynomial ring, so it cannot be toric (see Corollary 2.10 in "Mori dream spaces and GIT" by Hu and Keel; and see Example 4.1 in "The Cox ring of a spherical embedding" by Gagliardi for the Cox ring calculation).

I'm not sure if there is a "nice" general answer to my question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The Grassmannians, even $G(2,4)$, are not toric, since they are given by trinomials like $p_{1,2}p_{0,3}-p_{0,2}p_{1,3}+p_{0,1}p_{2,3}=0$ (plucker) and not binomials.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I think flag varieties with "small" parabolics will give this kind of behaviour in general (in your example, the parabolic is not maximal). My thought is that maybe the criteria is $G/P$ with $P$ a maximal parabolic, but I'm not sure why other parabolics won't work in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partial flag varieties satisfy a property called "being $\mathscr D$-affine". (This is the Beilinson-Bernstein localisation theorem). The following article  "[$\mathscr D$-affinity and toric varieties](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1435566)" prove that the only projective toric varieties that are $\mathscr D$-affine are product of projective spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, this is excellent! So the examples (2) that I list above are the only ones, which is a pretty nice answer to my question.